# Why is the InfluxDB Query API not timing out?

Tags: go, http, influxdb, flux-influxdb

I am querying InfluxDB from my Golang lambda function. While creating the client I am adding the timeout as follows:

```
influxClientOptions := influxdb2.DefaultOptions()
influxClientOptions.SetHTTPClient(retryClient.StandardClient())
influxClientOptions.SetHTTPRequestTimeout(1)    //Setting the timeout as 1 second here
client := influxdb2.NewClientWithOptions(host, token, influxClientOptions)
```

Then I am querying the InfluxDB with a query like:

```
queryAPI := client.QueryAPI("my_organization")
query := "from(bucket: ....." // Some query that takes more than 1 second
result, err := queryAPI.Query(context.Background(), query)
if err != nil {
    logging.FromContext(ctx).WithError(err).Error("influx query failed with error: ", err)
    return r, "Influx query failed"
}
if result.Err() != nil { // error raised during flux query response parsing
    logging.FromContext(ctx).WithError(result.Err()).Errorf("influx query error while parsing result: %s", result.Err())
    return r, "Influx query failed"
}
```

This query takes more than 1 second, but I am not getting any timeout error after 1 second.
My query is getting completed successfully instead of throwing error since the timeout set is 1 second.

What am I doing wrong here?

Expectation: I am expecting the query to stop the query and return an error after 1 second.

Comment: Could it be that http timeout is Not query timeout

Comment: Try context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)

Comment: `context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)` works fine. So I was wondering if there is any use of the `influxClientOptions.SetHTTPRequestTimeout(1)`?

Comment: Http timeout does Not mean query timeout i think

Comment: As far as I understand the code, using a request with a non-timeout context overwrites the timeout value of `influxClientOptions`, which in itself is just a convenience wrapper around `net/http` Client`s options.